# I have a problem running pygame 2.0 with python 3.9

Tags: python, pygame

I installed pygame using `pip install pygame` and when that didn't work I found a solution online and tried `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14`.
Still the same problem: "pygame" shows up when I do `pip list`, and pygame folders are there in the file locations. However, when I run the code `import pygame`, the shell shows the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `pip3 install pygame`

Comment: thanks that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You should do `pip3 install pygame` sometimes this happens, when you are on a mac and have 2 versions of python in your computer, MAC OS takes the python 2.7 by default, if you want a newer version, you have to specify by saying `python3` or `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.9, you can use: `python -m pip install pygame --pre --user`. This happens because python 3.9 isn't fully adapted to pygame yet.